# how to get an selected value fora dropdown control inside detailsview control. when it is in edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an detialsview  control with  item template and  edititemtemplate.
 when user  clciks the  edit  button in detailsview  all  the control  are replaced  with  textbox  control  and  dropdown control.  but in  dropdown  control
 i have  an issue
 **in the  read  mode  of detailsview  control   item template  field is having  value="India"**
 when i click  edit  mode here  now i am getting  dropdown control  with  populating all the countries. **as  for this  record the selected value  should be  "india"**    and then rest all the  countries  names  should be coming  in dropdown control

my code  looks like this

```
public DataSet PopulateDropDownList()

{

SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString);

SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM country", myConnection);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ad.Fill(ds, "country");

return ds; 

}
<ItemTemplate >
```

' runat ="server" >
    
    
 
" 
DataTextField="Phone" DataValueField = "PhoneID">

so in edit  mode how can i  show user  the    the this selected  value  in the  dropdown  should   comefirst then follwd  by other  countries name

how can  i achive this one  here.   looking for this solution from past  2 days
  any help  would  be great 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet isn't complete, I think.

However: unless you have something to haul out the SelectedValue of the drop-down list and put it first, the drop-down list will have entries in the same order as the database query.